# How to integrate functions involving absolute value?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\displaystyle b_n = \frac{2}{10}\int\limits_{0}^{10} 4 - 0.8 \vert x - 5 \vert  \bigg(\frac{\sin(nx\pi)}{10}\bigg) \, dx$

This is in regards to my previous question, which I have deleted due to my incorrect working. 
**Question**

Find the temperature, u(x,t) in a bar of silver (length = 10 cm, constant cross section of area 1 cm2, density 10.6 g/cm3, thermal conductivity 1.04 cal/(sec cm$ ^oC)$, specific heat 0.056 cal/($g^ oC$) that is perfectly insulated laterally, whose ends are kept at temperature $0^o C$ and initial
temperature $f(x)^o C$ , where $f(x) = 4 - 0.8 | x - 5 |$

In my solution this where I am stuck:

[image]

Comment: When dealing with absolute values in integrals, break it into pieces. In this case, break it into an integral from 0 to 5 and then 5 to 10.

Comment: @Cameron Williams:  Thanks,  I will try that out.